# What makes a logic statement a tautology?

Tags: logic

Let the statement be $((P\vee Q)\oplus T)\Rightarrow (P\star Q)$. $\star$ being what binary connectives can the statement be a tautology?

This is my first time to encounter this kind of problem so I need some hints.

Comment: First, are you familiar what exactly a tautology means?

Comment: @clementine1001 I know. An always-true statement regardless of the value of literals.

Comment: Okay great! If you take a look on the wiki page about tautology, there is a section about "Verifying tautologies": "One algorithmic method for verifying that every valuation makes the formula to be true is to make a truth table that includes every possible valuation."

Comment: Does $T$ stand for 'True'? Or is it a variable that may have either truth value?

Comment: @paw88789 $T$ is just a variable.

Comment: @paw88789 The truth table of $A \lor B$, for example, is just a convenient, informal way to represent the theorem $(A \land B \to A\lor B)~\land ~ (A \land \neg B \to A\lor B)~\land~ (\neg A \land B \to A\lor B)~\land~ (\neg A \land \neg B \to \neg (A\lor B))$ The T and F symbols are not variables or constants. In a truth table, they are just entries in that table.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches, I'll outline a less algorithmic approach here. First note that if $((P \vee Q) \oplus T)$ is false then this statement is true, so we only need to consider the cases where $((P \vee Q) \oplus T)$ is true. This occurs only when $P \vee Q$ is true and $T$ is false or $P \vee Q$ is false and $T$ is true. Now note since $P \star Q$ does not include $T$ and must be true in both these cases, $P \star Q$ must be true when $P \vee Q$ is true and when $P \vee Q$ is false. But this encompasses all values of values of $P$ and $Q$, hence $P \star Q$ must be true for all values of $P,Q$.